# Image aspect ratio maintainence not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am working on the web app, in which i have to use images of different size. I have to show image in appropriate aspect ratio.

My ImageWrapper is of **dimention 500x500**.
I am using a directive to maintain aspect ratio.

This is **hml file**

```
 <div class="image-aspect-wrapper-list ">
    <img src="/OctoberImageHolder/container/2/small/1.jpeg"  alt="..." onError="" image-resize >
</div>
```

this is **css file**

```
.image-aspect-wrapper-list { 
   width: 250px; 
   height: 250px;  
   text-align: center; 
   line-height: 250px; margin: 0 auto; 
} 
.image-aspect-wrapper-list img {
 vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

this is the **directive**

```
MyApp.directive('imageResize', function($window, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('load', function(){
              if($(this).width() >= $(this).height()){  
                  $(this).css({'width':$(this).parent().width(),'height':'auto'});

              }else{
               $(this).css({'height':$(this).parent().height(),'width':'auto'});
              }

            });
        }
    };
});
```

This is working fine but it takes some time to load the directive and upto that time image getting of maximum size.
how to tackle this issue.

Some time it's not working properly.

Comment: why are you setting the height at all? just use img {width:100%} (not setting height)

Comment: that scinario fails for portrait images which have height larger then width

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lbe251qw/